# How can I get certain information from an HTML webpage?

Tags: c#, html, html-parsing

I would like to pull a statistic from a web page, but I have absolutely no idea how to.
For example, on this web page, https://www.google.ca/ , I would like to get the text of the button "I'm Feeling Lucky" from the HTML code, or a simpler way if possible. I have code, but it doesn't really relate well to my question. If you could please help, that would be great.

EDIT: I'm using C# Windows Forms Application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this link may helps you

http://www.dotnetperls.com/scraping-html

and if you are doing with java

http://htmlcleaner.sourceforge.net/javause.php

Best Of Luck

Answer (score 0):

```
<html> 
<body>
  <form action="get_btn_val.php" method="GET">
     <input type="submit" name="btn_click" value="I'm Feeling Lucky" >
  </form> 
</body>
</html>
```

//inthe get_btn_val.php page

```
<?php
   echo $_GET['btn_click'] ;
?>
```

Comment: How would I add this to a Windows Form Application?

Comment: sry i didn't thout abt C#

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about C#, but you would need an html parsing library. Python's [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) is incredibly powerful. I would give it a look.

Answer (score 0):

I must say that your question is unclear. It is difficult to give concrete answer, so I can only try my best to give you some starting points. From the tag, I guess you are finding ways to parse the HTML file from a site?

First, as you tagged C# in this question, I guess you may want to find solution in C# first? You may take a look at [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)

There are also similar libraries in other language.

PHP: [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)

Python: [official HTML parser](https://docs.python.org/2/library/htmlparser.html)

Java: [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/)

Or, it would be easiest to use javascript (or jquery or other javascript library) to parse HTML. However, notice that if the HTML is not host your own machine, you cannot use javascript to parse the HTML of that page because of same-origin policy. You will need to run the javascript in other way though, like running in the developer tools console, in chrome-extension script or run in server side node.js.